# Unable to update iOS project version

Tags: ios

I'm having an issue uploading my new app version to the app store via xcode.

The error I'm getting is "the bundle is invalid.  The value for key CFBundleVersion / CFBundleShortVersionString in the info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version [1.0.2]"

I cant find the info.plist file, but I did find a file that was [projectname]-info.plist which I assume is what they're referring to.

In this file I changed the values of bundle versions string, short to 2.0 as well as bundle version to 2.0

I checked the summary of my project target and saw the version was 2.0 as well as the build..

Even after this it still tells me the version of my project is 1.0 in the organizer - archives tab.

I had issues with provisioning profiles and certificates earlier, possibly this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the version is the same in the Info tab as well as the summary tab. The summary tab should be updating the info tab automatically.

Comment: the info tab and summary tab reflect the same version, I'm starting to think this is maybe some sort of weird provisioning profile issue.

Comment: Possibly, the provisioning profiles are so finicky. Do you have the same version number in iTunes connect?

Comment: the current version in iTunes connect is 1.0.2..

I've specified version and build 2.0 in the target's summary tab in xcode. 

When I go to submit the app thru xcode it says my version is still 1.0?

Comment: You need to prep iTunes connect for a binary. Make the binary version 2.0 when prepping iTunes connect, the version in Xcode must match what you set it to in iTunes connect.